# Find the best place to overlay text on an image?

Tags: visualization, html, computer-vision, text-formatting, web

I need to put text over a background image to make a nice looking banner. In order to find the best place to put it, I'd like to know the "focus points" of the image (basically the centers of mass of the foreground) to get the placement and alignment of the text just right.

Here's example images:

```
i1 = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/70ae5e00-41c7-464a-a341-d4499f667deb"];
i2 = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/358374b6-5e47-41a6-a3b5-acfbe2de8a25"];
i3 = CloudGet@
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b7e329c0-7987-4473-881b-d9cc4d09ec31";
```

Here are some simple design rules I'd prefer to follow:

- Position the text so margins are equal
- Line up the text with people's heads
- Align/justify text toward the focal centers so that you don't divide people's attention

If there are any hackers with design experience out there, how would you do this with computer vision and/or heuristics?